# How best to make a "composite key" in value field (Blazor)

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to write a component to which it will be possible to pass a list, the elements of which should be clickable and additional information should be displayed when clicked. However, I have a problem with the implementation. Admit: I have a list of groups, I need to get a list of students from all groups (one list for all groups at once). The problem is that students have hardcore identifiers that are unique only WITHIN ONE group. What I mean: in the group "Mathematics" there are students with ID: 1, 2, 4, 9. In the group "Physics" there may also be students with ID: 1, 2, 4, 9, but these are actually other people from another group. Roughly speaking, I can't manipulate non-unique values (I can't give each a unique number to the database - I won't go into details). I can somehow designate uniqueness in **@bind** by two parameters (group.Id, students.Id)?

```
       <List TOption="VM.Student"
             TextField="@(option => option.Name)"
             ValueField="@(option => option.Id)" //perfect, if a unique value (this is not the case with me)
             @bind-Value="???"
             Options="_students" />
```

Component:

```
@inherits InputBase<string>
@typeparam TOption

<div>
    @if (Options is not null)
    {
        <div>
            @foreach (var option in Options)
            {
                var text = TextField?.Invoke(option);
                var value = ValueField?.Invoke(option);
                var isSelected = CurrentValue == value;

                <div class="@(isSelected ? " selected" :  string.Empty)">
                    <div @onclick="eventArgs => { OnChange(value, isSelected); }">
                       
            }
     </div>
}
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public IEnumerable<TOption> Options { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Func<TOption, string> TextField { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Func<TOption, string> ValueField { get; set; }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out string result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = CurrentValue;
        validationErrorMessage = string.Empty;
        return true;
    }

    private void OnChange(string value, bool isSelected)
    {
        if (!isSelected)
        {
            if (ValueChanged.HasDelegate)
            {
                ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
            }

            EditContext?.NotifyFieldChanged(FieldIdentifier);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand which problem you are facing. If you have a List of groups than you can simple load all students for each group indiviually. Could you provide maybe more code or describe your issue a bit more? :)

Comment: Why are you inheriting from InputBase? What is being displayed as options and what exactly should happen OnChange?

Comment: @MarvinKlein Attached the component code. The problem is that I don't quite understand how to distinguish these students in the component. That is, if I now select a student with ID=1 in my list, then he will stand out in all groups in which there is a student.ID=1. I am interested in how to correctly circumvent this point. Sorry if anything, I haven't been working with Blazor for so long :(

Comment: @MarvinKlein The fields of the transmitted list are displayed as an option: "Name" and so on. When you click on a specific name, additional data on this "student" should be displayed. Is it better to do it differently?

Comment: So options are your student objects?

Comment: yes, options is student objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read this correctly:

1. You have a semi generic component to display a list of items.
2. You have a unique key problem because the database uses int ids.

I understand why you are trying to use `InputBase`, but the `EditContext` confuses me a little, so I may have missed something important!

First data classes.  Records (unless you are editing data) to make equality checking simple:

```cs
public record StudentKey(int StudentId, int GroupId);

public record Student(StudentKey Uid, string Name, string Grade);
```

I've mocked a data pipeline into a ViewModel/Presenter DI service:

```cs
public class StudentPresenter
{
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students = Enumerable.Empty<Student>();

    public async ValueTask LoadData()
    {
        // Fake a real async api/db get
        await Task.Delay(100);
        var list = new List<Student>();
        list.AddRange(MathematicsStudents);
        list.AddRange(PhysicsStudents);
        this.Students = list;
    }

    public Student? GetStudent(StudentKey? value)
        => Students.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Uid == value);

    private List<Student> MathematicsStudents = new()
    {
        new(new StudentKey(1, 1), "Fred", "A++"),
        new(new StudentKey(2, 1), "Jon", "A"),
        new(new StudentKey(3, 1), "Liz", "B-"),
    };

    private List<Student> PhysicsStudents = new()
    {
        new(new StudentKey(1, 2), "Clare", "A++"),
        new(new StudentKey(2, 2), "Dave", "A"),
        new(new StudentKey(3, 2), "Alice", "B-"),
    };
}
```

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<StudentPresenter>();
```

I've used an existing component I have to do your list.  It's very similar to what you have.  It doesn't inherit from `InputBase`, but does use the binding framework to update a field in the parent component.  I've also used the Bootstrap ListGroup to "prettyfy" the display. My original control is actually a select which you can see here in another answer - [Blazor pass binding to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75409784/blazor-pass-binding-to-child-component/75412377#75412377).

```cs
@typeparam TItem
@typeparam TValue

<ul class="list-group">
    @foreach (var option in this.ItemsProvider)
    {
        <li class="@this.GetItemCss(option)" @onclick="() => this.OnSelected(option)">@this.GetText(option)</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    [Parameter] public TValue? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TValue> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public IEnumerable<TItem> ItemsProvider { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<TItem>();
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Func<TItem, string>? TextProvider { get; set; }
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Func<TItem, TValue>? ValueProvider { get; set; }

    private string GetItemCss(TItem value)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(ValueProvider);
        if (this.Value is null)
            return "list-group-item";

        return this.Value.Equals(ValueProvider(value)) ? "list-group-item active" : "list-group-item";
    }

    private string GetText(TItem value)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(TextProvider);
        return TextProvider(value);
    }

    private void OnSelected(TItem value)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(ValueProvider);
        ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(ValueProvider(value));
    }
}
```

And then the demo page:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject StudentPresenter Presenter
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<MyDisplay 
    TItem="Student" 
    ItemsProvider="this.Presenter.Students" 
    TValue="StudentKey" 
    TextProvider="(Student item) => item.Name" 
    ValueProvider="(Student item) => item.Uid"
    @bind-Value=this.studentKey
    />

    <div class="alert alert-info m-3">
        Student Grade: @this.GetStudentGrade
    </div>

@code {
    private StudentKey? studentKey;

    private string GetStudentGrade => this.Presenter.GetStudent(studentKey)?.Grade ?? "No Student Selected";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Presenter.LoadData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you gave me a huge boost, and I solved my problem! Special thanks for the time you spent on the written example :)

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have a List of your students allready I would do something like this for the component.

```
@foreach(var student in Students)
{
    <div @onclick="() => StudentClicked(student)">

    </div>
}
@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public List<Stundent> Students { get; set; } = new List<Student>();

    private void OnStudentClicked(Student student)
    {
        // TODO: Make whatever you want with your student object
    }
}
```

If you want to return the student, you should add an EventCallback like this.

```
@foreach(var student in Students)
{
    <div @onclick="() => OnStudentClickedAsync(student)">

    </div>
}
@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public List<Stundent> Students { get; set; } = new List<Student>();
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public EventCallback<Student> OnStudentClicked;
    private async Task OnStudentClickedAsync(Student student)
    {
        // TODO: Make whatever you want with your student object
        await OnStudentClicked.InvokeAsync(student);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I took something in common between the two answers and I succeeded. two answers suit me :))))